# ListView Custom Adapter repeat items

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

Whats wrong with this adapter, when i scroll down i see repeated rows at the bottom and then when scroll up again i see also repeated rows at the top that were not exist before, and the rest of `Data` items does not appear

the adapter:

```
public class ClassesListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> Data = new ArrayList<>();


    public ClassesListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data) {
        Data = data;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Data.size();
    }
    private class ViewHolder{

        TextView ClassDataTV;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.classes_list_view_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ClassDataTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ClassDataTV);
            holder.ClassDataTV.setText(Data.get(position));
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and here how i use it:

```
    ArrayList<String> v = new ArrayList<>();
    v.add("AAAAAAA");
    v.add("WWWWWwW");
    v.add("VVVVVVV");
    v.add("SSSSSSSSS");
    v.add("QQQQQQQQQ");
    v.add("YYYYYYYY");
    v.add("TTTTTTT");
    v.add("UUUUUUUUUU");
    v.add("zzzzzzzzzzzz");
    v.add("CCCCCCCCCC");
    v.add("HHHHHHHHHHH");
    v.add("IIIIIIIIII");
    v.add("PPPPPPPPP");
    mListView.setAdapter(new ClassesListViewAdapter(getActivity(), v));
```

Comment: did you change visibility in your adapter ?

Comment: The same thing happened to me, but my items repeated periodically like: A, B, C, D, A, B, C, D and so on. I fixed it with a solution I found here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Vucko, Link is not working

Comment: @Amir, No but I calling `setAdapter` at `onResume` , will that be a problem ?

Comment: it's not recommend to setAdapter in onResume if I were you I do it in OnCreate | onCreatedView | onViewCreate

Comment: @Amir, ok, i will take ur advice into consideration- Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put following part of your code outside if-block and it will be fixed :

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.classes_list_view_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ClassDataTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ClassDataTV);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

      // initialize your view here 
        holder.ClassDataTV.setText(Data.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
```

The logic behind **ViewHolder** pattern tells that you should do it in this way. when you scroll some of reference will not created again and `else block` called so this cause your list not updated as you expected.

Comment: While this is true you should also explain why.

Comment: Yes, it Worked perfectly

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995052/repeating-items-in-listview) is related to your problem and [the selected answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995052/repeating-items-in-listview) may shed some like.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla, Thanks