# Can I add listener in the receiving element of a listView?

Tags: android, listener

I have a `ListView` with the following `Adapter` :

```
public class gestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sav> {

    public gestionAdapter(Context context, List<Sav> savs){
        super(context, 0, savs);
    }
     @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_gestion,parent, false);
        }
         Sav sav = getItem(position);
        ViewHolderGestion viewHolder = (ViewHolderGestion) convertView.getTag();
        if(viewHolder == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderGestion();
            viewHolder.titreSav = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TitreSav);
            viewHolder.intervenant = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.interv);
            viewHolder.client = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cli);
            viewHolder.archive = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.archive);
            viewHolder.actif = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.actif);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.archive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "archive ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
            viewHolder.actif.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "actif ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        viewHolder.titreSav.setText(sav.getTitre());
        viewHolder.intervenant.setText(sav.getIntervenant());
        viewHolder.client.setText(sav.getNomClient());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

As you notice, there are two `buttons` for each row. At the moment, I've put the listeners in the `Adapter` But is it possible to put these listeners in the receiving view, so I can use these buttons to refresh my View for example?

At the moment I've tried to make some of the functions of my View public, but I'm not satisfied at all with that solution.

Comment: I dont understand you completely but You can put listener for your Root layout too. Also your ViewHolder pattern logic in your Adapter is not correct.

Comment: it seems I can't access these elements from the Activity that displays the listView

Comment: You can either put listner on root layout, put listner on  listView 
someListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("############","Items " +  MoreItems[arg2] );
            }

        });

Comment: You should define listener in your adapter and notify that.

Comment: I understand the general concept of what you guys tell me, but do you know where I could find a commented sample of code? I'm not that good on that aspect of android developement, it would help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things to mention your viewHolder pattern is not correct take look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037746/listview-custom-adapter-repeat-items/37037861#37037861).

Second thing is that if you want to access to your rootLayout inside activity easiest way is define Listener in your Adapter and then notify that in your Activity.

for example define following interface in your Adapter and create instance in your adapter :

```
private OnBackClickListener onBackClickListener;

 public interface OnBackClickListener {
        void onBackClick();
    }
```

Then when your rootLayout clicked in your adapter call following method :

```
rootView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (onBackClickListener != null) {
                    onBackClickListener.onBackClick();
                }
            }
        });
```

In your activity pass this listener to your Adapter like this :

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context,new OnBackClickListener(){//rest of things});
```

Now in your Activity when rootLayout clicked `OnBackClickListener` of your Adapter notify you.

In case of `RecyclerView` you can find complete implementation [here](https://github.com/AmirHadifar/Flashcard).

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll try both methods and see what fits me the most

Answer (score 0):

You can add the listeners to your activity but you wont be able to point out which view has been clicked.Instead you can do it like this

```
public static class ViewHolderTwo extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView dictionaryWord;
    private TextView dictionaryShortcut;
    private CheckBox deleteWord;
    public interface Listener
    { public void viewOneclicked();
       public void viewTwoClicked();
    }
    private Listener mListener;


    public ViewHolderTwo(View v,Listener listener) {
        super(v);
        this.mListener = listener;
        dictionaryWord = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dictionaryWord);
        dictionaryShortcut = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dictionaryShortcut);
        deleteWord = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteWord);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == dictionaryWord)
        {
        mListener.viewOneClicked();
        return;
       }
}
```

and make your activity implement listener and pass its reference in viewholders constructor

Comment: And this way i'll be able to use the methods in my activity in the listener?

Comment: Yes you can use activity methods with viewholder by casting it to activity and checking for null pointer.But make sure that you wont hold any references to listener if the activity is no longer in memory